# Android Studio cannot detect the installed support repository

Tags: android-sdk-manager, android-studio-3.4

After reinstalling Android Studio (with SDK v28) and opening a project that used to work, it asks for libraries whose SDK is already installed.

Build error:
[image: Build error]

Installed SDK:
[image: Installed SDK]

It also asks for Android Support Repo which is already installed as shown below:
[image: Installed SDK Tools]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the whole local "support repository" and remove the `-alpha1` tag.

This dependency can be met with repository `google()` or `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: @Shessuky most likely you don't have either of the stated repositories added or are working in offline mode. Based upon some screenshot this only permits assumptions... while it' still likely that either repository had not been configured for the project (this has absolutely nothing to do with Android Studio, but Gradle). add the `build.gradle` to the question, if you don't know how to fix it.